# How to override an attribute in a child class which is used in its parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, parent-child

```
class Car():
    """A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + " " + self.make + " " + self.model
        return long_name.title()

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes of the parrent class."""

        super().__init__(make, model, year)


my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
```

How do I remove the attribute `year` from the `class ElectricCar(Car)`?
I want the attribute `year` to still be in the parent class `class Car()`, but to be removed from the child class.

Comment: And what about `get_descriptive_name` method after removing `year`?

Comment: If you don't want your `ElectricCar` class to have a year attribute you shouldn't make it a subclass of `Car`. Either you don't understand how subclassing and inheritance work or you need mentoring on how to design the proper classes for the problem being solved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, but this is not right to do it. if `year` shouldn't be used in `ElectricCar` then it must be somewhere in another class or object. this is not right to put something in parent and remove it in the child. but by the way, you can do it like this:

```
class ElectricCar(Car):

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        del self.year
```

> Note that removing year will raise `AttributeError` in `get_descriptive_name`. because there is no year.

Comment: Why must "year" be somewhere in another class or object?

Comment: You put all common attrs in the parent class, what is the usage of `year`?

Comment: The "year" is used in the method "get_descriptive_name()".

Comment: I want to see if it is possible to remove `year` from the child class, but so that it's still left in the parent class